# How to check if com object is already running and get instance of it

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, com, office-interop

I'm using the below line to Instantiate a Outlook Application Instance:

`Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application()`

I would like to... check if Outlook Instance is already running and if so, get and use that instead

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Outlook.Application oApp;

Process[] outlookProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");

if (outlookProcs.Length > 0)
{
    oApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
}
else 
{
    oApp = new Outlook.Application();
}
```